# setOnClickListener error

Tags: java, android, onclick

This is my source code. **I just have error in setOnClickListener. I don't know what's wrong inside of setOnClickListener.** I have trace all code, the error is in setOnClickListener...

I have search question like this. But I don't find answer which I want. 
And I'm newbie android programmer

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    TextView diceScore;
    RelativeLayout mainLayout;
    Button shakeDice;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
         shakeDice = (Button) findViewById(R.id.shakeDice);

        shakeDice.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                randomDiceNumber();
            }
        });

    }


    public void randomDiceNumber() { 
        int diceNumber = 0;
        int max = 6;
        int min = 1;

        Random r = new Random();
        diceNumber = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
        diceScore = new TextView(this);
        diceScore.setText(diceNumber);
        diceScore.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT) );
        mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
        mainLayout.addView(diceScore);

    }


    }
```

My Import after I edit Button.OnClickListener to View.OnClickListener

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
```

LogCat[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the roll result assignment

```
diceScore.setText(String.valueOf(diceNumber));
```

and OnClickListener type to

```
android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

and try it the following way (note the imports). You only have to adjust the position of the roll result TextView to your liking

```
import java.util.Random;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main extends Activity {
    TextView diceScore;
    RelativeLayout mainLayout;
    Button shakeDice;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        shakeDice = (Button) findViewById(R.id.shakeDice);


    shakeDice.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            randomDiceNumber();

        }
    });

}


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void randomDiceNumber() { 
    int diceNumber = 0;
    int max = 6;
    int min = 1;

    Random r = new Random();
    diceNumber = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
    diceScore = new TextView(this);
    diceScore.setText(String.valueOf(diceNumber));
    diceScore.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT)         );
    mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
    mainLayout.addView(diceScore);

    }
}
```

Here's the layout XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Main" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/shakeDice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="66dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

If you push the button multiple times, the results will overlay themselves, so check if diceScore is Instantiated when rolling and just change the text.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
new View.OnClickListener()
```

Comment: your imports!

Delete it all.  Reorg imports.  type out using content assist.

Comment: Is setOnClickListener on line 24?

Comment: in line 24 is shakeDice = (Button) findViewById(R.id.shakeDice);

Comment: Then i think it as user3226185 say.
your button was not found.
Try to debug and watch "findViewById(R.id.shakeDice)".

Comment: May be your R.layout.main doen't contain shakeDice.

Comment: there is 2 main.xml. I've delete one main.xml, but still error. main.xml which I use is inside of layout-land folder

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you post your main.xml together with the code.

Base on your code, shakeDice seems to be Null,and it will throw a NullPointerException when setOnClickListener.

Comment: its not null after findviewbyid

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass int where the method asks for a String parameter.

```
int diceNumber = 0;
diceScore.setText(diceNumber);
```

try this.

```
diceScore.setText(String.valueOf(diceNumber));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way
    TextView diceScore;
    RelativeLayout mainLayout;
    Button shakeDice;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        shakeDice = (Button) findViewById(R.id.shakeDice);

        // here you set View.OnClickListener rather than Button.OnClickListener
        shakeDice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                randomDiceNumber();
            }
        });

    }


    public void randomDiceNumber() {
        int diceNumber;
        int max = 6;
        int min = 1;

        Random r = new Random();
        diceNumber = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
        diceScore = new TextView(this);
        // here TextView setText() accept String or CharacterSequence so can't gave int becz when gave as int it's try finding String from value.xml like String resource
        diceScore.setText(String.valueOf(diceNumber));
        diceScore.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT) );
        mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
        try{
            mainLayout.removeAllViews();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mainLayout.addView(diceScore);

}
```

Comment: still error, thank you. why it can error ? because I run main.xml in folder layout-land. It mean I run landscape main.xml